# How do I search for first and last names in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make users able to perform complex searches from a simple database table.

**Table**

```
id, name
3,  Esteban Julio Ricardo Montoya De la Rosa Ramirez
4,  Romeo Heartless
5,  Rick Testing Astley
6,  Never Going to Give
```

How do I make it possible to recieve row 3, when the input is either "Esteban Montoya", "Esteban la Rosa Remirez", "Ramirez" etc.? The application is programmed in PHP.

Comment: By storing the First and Last names in different fields.

Comment: Is that one person with many middle names, or different persons?

Comment: Yes these need to be separate columns in your table. But you could use LIKE or REGEXP as your search condition.

Comment: Please read some documentation, and come back and ask again if you fail in your implementation. Here is a good starting point: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-full-text-search.aspx

Comment: Please consider database normalization. Put first and last names etc. in separate fields.

Comment: If you want to keep the simple table (although I would strongly consider splitting it into multiple columns), a quick and dirty way would be to split your search String in PHP and adding a like clause for every single word.  

E.g.
SELECT *
FROM Names
WHERE name LIKE '%Esteban%' OR name LIKE '%Montoya%' OR name LIKE ... (you get the idea)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql search for a catid in a text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168583/mysql-search-for-a-catid-in-a-text-field) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281763/is-it-possible-to-search-for-whole-given-word-in-full-text-search-of-mysql or several other MySQL full text search questions.

Comment: @Siyual . . . You might be interested in this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_naming_customs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use wildcards:

```
where name like concat('%', replace($userinput, ' ', '%'), '%')
```

Note:  This still requires that the names be in the right order (which is what your examples suggest that you want).

Comment: Don't you need a leading and a trailing `%` too?

Comment: @jarlh . . . Yes, that would make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Could use `REGEXP 'Esteban Montoya|Esteban la Rosa Remirez|Ramirez'`

Answer (score 1):

you can use a query like this. it return every row that contains both words in the field.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE `name` LIKE '%Esteban%' 
  AND `name` LIKE '%Montoya%';
```

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad364/1

Still requires the search terms to appear in the right order, but it seems to work adding `%` to the beginning, end and replace all spaces :)

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%Esteban%Ricardo%';
```